# How to redefine a symbol/character to be interpreted as a """ (triple quotes) symbol in Scala code?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, dsl

For example, suppose I wanted to redefine the bang symbol to mean the same thing as triple quotes in Scala for a DSL.

Then I would want

!Hello world!

to mean the same thing as

"""Hello world"""

in Scala source code. (Essentially, this might be similar to a #DEFINE in C.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the behavior of """ is a built-in feature of the language (see section 1.3.5 of [the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)) and any alias for it would require support in the lexical parser, I don't think this is possible using normal means.  Even the [macro processor](http://scalamacros.org/) doesn't work at that low a level.